# Javascript: Image not matching value of radio button

Tags: javascript

I am working with radio buttons and displaying an image depending on the radio button chosen. But somehow I am receiving an error with the image array. I only get two pictures displayed and does not match the proper value. Is the error in my array or the html? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

Reference of bikes:

- [Bike1.jpg](http://gear.dirtrider.com/2011-kawasaki-kx-450f.html)
- [Bike2.jpg](http://www.motorcyclecruiser.com/2010/yamaha/road_star/s/54875/05/)
- [Bike3.jpg](http://www.motorcyclistonline.com/2010/aprilia/rsv4/r/55445/05/)

**JS**

```
<script>
 function check_value(val) { 
       var imgs = ['images/bike1.jpg', 'images/bike2.jpg', 'images/bike3.jpg'];
       var img = imgs[val];
       var el = document.getElementById("imgBox");
       if (img) {
         el.src = img;
         el.style.display = "";
       }

     }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="builder">
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1)'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2)'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3)'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox" src="#" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays start at index `0`, so you have the following alternatives:

- use `imgs[val-1]`
- change your array to `[null, "img1", "img2 ...]`
- start your images at `img0`

However, a **much better** approach is:

```
function check_value(val) {
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox");
    if (val>0 && val<4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3], modify it according to your needs
        el.src = "images/bike" + val + ".jpg";
        el.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this method much better

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are zero-indexed. You should call:

```
check_value(0)
```

to get the first item, and 1 for the second, 2 for the third.

Note how choosing your first item loads the second image, and the second item the third.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays are indexed starting from 0 and going up. So

```
<form name="builder">
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1)'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2)'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3)'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>
```

Should be

```
<form name="builder">
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(0)'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(1)'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
   <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(2)'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>
```